# Pandas Melt : Columns to Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my first SO question after three days of learning Python on my own so please be lenient.

I have concatenated four dataframes :

```
frames = [dfLocationID, dfDimensions, dfCategories, dfTags]  
result = pd.concat(frames,
                   ignore_index=True,
                   sort=False)
```

To get this :

```
        Location ID   Dimensions     Categories              Tags
    0        1000.0          NaN            NaN               NaN
    1           NaN  3,000 sq ft            NaN               NaN
    2           NaN          NaN  * In the Zone               NaN
    3           NaN          NaN      Apartment               NaN
    4           NaN          NaN           Loft               NaN
    5           NaN          NaN            NaN          Bohemian
    6           NaN          NaN            NaN          Colorful
    7           NaN          NaN            NaN   Eclectic Quirky
    8           NaN          NaN            NaN           Kitchen
    9           NaN          NaN            NaN       Living Room
    10          NaN          NaN            NaN             Piano
    11          NaN          NaN            NaN        Wood Floor
```

I would like to achieve this:

```
        Location ID   Dimensions        Item              Data
    0        1000.0  3,000 sq ft  Categories     * In the Zone
    1        1000.0  3,000 sq ft  Categories         Apartment
    2        1000.0  3,000 sq ft  Categories              Loft
    3        1000.0  3,000 sq ft        Tags          Bohemian
    4        1000.0  3,000 sq ft        Tags          Colorful
    5        1000.0  3,000 sq ft        Tags   Eclectic Quirky
    6        1000.0  3,000 sq ft        Tags           Kitchen
    7        1000.0  3,000 sq ft        Tags       Living Room
    8        1000.0  3,000 sq ft        Tags             Piano
    9        1000.0  3,000 sq ft        Tags        Wood Floor
```

Then I tried this :

```
dfTemp = ((dfLocationID.join(dfDimensions, how='outer')).join(dfCategories, how='outer')).join(dfTags, how='outer')
```

To get this :

```
       Location ID   Dimensions     Categories              Tags
    0       1000.0  3,000 sq ft  * In the Zone          Bohemian
    1          NaN          NaN      Apartment          Colorful
    2          NaN          NaN           Loft   Eclectic Quirky
    3          NaN          NaN            NaN           Kitchen
    4          NaN          NaN            NaN       Living Room
    5          NaN          NaN            NaN             Piano
    6          NaN          NaN            NaN        Wood Floor
```

Now I'm trying to convert the last two columns to rows :

```
dfFinal = dfTemp.melt(id_vars=["Location ID", "Dimensions"],
                          var_name="Item",
                          value_name="Data")
```

But I get this :

```
        Location ID   Dimensions        Item              Data
    0        1000.0  3,000 sq ft  Categories     * In the Zone
    1           NaN          NaN  Categories         Apartment
    2           NaN          NaN  Categories              Loft
    3           NaN          NaN  Categories               NaN
    4           NaN          NaN  Categories               NaN
    5           NaN          NaN  Categories               NaN
    6           NaN          NaN  Categories               NaN
    7        1000.0  3,000 sq ft        Tags          Bohemian
    8           NaN          NaN        Tags          Colorful
    9           NaN          NaN        Tags   Eclectic Quirky
    10          NaN          NaN        Tags           Kitchen
    11          NaN          NaN        Tags       Living Room
    12          NaN          NaN        Tags             Piano
    13          NaN          NaN        Tags        Wood Floor
```

Any ideas on how to clean the data ?  Additionally, I will have to iterate through different Location IDs and the number of values in Categories and Tags will not be constant.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the content of `dfLocationID, dfDimensions, dfCategories, dfTags`?

Comment: I've tried a different method to join the four dfs :

`dfTemp = ((dfLocationID.join(dfDimensions, how='outer')).join(dfCategories, how='outer')).join(dfTags, how='outer')`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd convert the `NaN`s to `None`, as they are easier to handle:

```
df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
```

Then, you want the whole first and second column to have the same values (I don't know where you make that assumption):

```
df['Location ID'] = df['Location ID'].iloc[0]
df['Dimensions'] = df['Dimensions'].iloc[1]
```

Then you can run your melt function as it is. Now you only have to filter out all rows that either are `None` in the "Item" or the "Data" column:

```
df = df[~(df["Item"].isnull() | df["Data"].isnull())]
```

Then, the output is as you want it:

```
Location ID Dimensions  Item    Data
2   1000.0  3000 sq ft  Categories  * In the Zone
3   1000.0  3000 sq ft  Categories  Apartment
4   1000.0  3000 sq ft  Categories  Loft
17  1000.0  3000 sq ft  Tags    Bohemian
18  1000.0  3000 sq ft  Tags    Colorful
19  1000.0  3000 sq ft  Tags    Eclectic Quirky
20  1000.0  3000 sq ft  Tags    Kitchen
21  1000.0  3000 sq ft  Tags    Living Room
22  1000.0  3000 sq ft  Tags    Piano
23  1000.0  3000 sq ft  Tags    Wood Floor
```

If you need to do this for different locations, you pack this procedure into a function `transform` and use `groupby`:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
for name, group in df.groupby(['Location ID', 'Dimensions']):
    df_group = transform(group)
    pd.concat([df_new, df_group], axis=0)
```